# YUI Panel and scrolling

Tags: scroll, yui, panel

I have a draggable YUI Panel defined like this

```
new YAHOO.widget.Panel("parameters", {
                        fixedcenter: true,
                        constraintoviewport: true,
                        underlay: "shadow",
                        visible: false,
                        close: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        width: "350px" });
```

When the panel is shown, I want it to remain always visible, even when the window is scrolled.
This is also the case, thanks to `fixedcenter: true`. The problem is that when the window is scrolled the panel positions itself to the center of the window even if it was dragged somewhere else previously.

How should I modify the above definition so that the position of the panel remains constant relative to the window when the window is scrolled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your panel container in a wrapper element that has fixed positioning, e.g.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: fixed">
    <div id="parameters">
        <div class="hd">Header</div>
        <div class="bd">Hello, this is my awesome panel.</div>
        <div class="ft">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Construct your panel without the `fixedcenter` configuration property, and center the panel immediately after you render it, e.g.

```
var panel = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("parameters", {
        constraintoviewport: true,
        underlay: "shadow",
        visible: false,
        close: true,
        draggable: true,
        width: "350px"
    });
panel.render();
panel.center();
```

The panel should now stay in the same position when the window is scrolled. I only tested this in Firefox 3.0 and Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

I've [posted the source](http://pastebin.com/f3b4861bf) of a self-contained example that will demonstrate this working.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, set the fixedcenter to:

> **"contained"** To enable fixed center positioning, as with the true
>   option. However, unlike setting the property to true, when the
>   property is set to "contained", if the overlay is too big for the
>   viewport, it will not get automatically centered when the user scrolls
>   or resizes the window (until the window is large enough to contain the
>   overlay). This is useful in cases where the Overlay has both header
>   and footer UI controls which the user may need to access.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Overlay.html